# Custom Domain visualization

Tags: sqlanywhere

I'm storing .NET TimeSpan objects in a SQL Anywhere database as their underlying .NET implementation type, a 64-bit integer.  I've even created a custom domain called "timespan" to do so.

When debugging in Visual Studio, you can override the default `ToString()` for the debugger window so that it shows what you want.  I'm looking for a similar capability in SQL Anywhere.

Does anyone know if there's a way to specify a visualizer (or a format string, or anything) so that when interactively browsing a SQL Anywhere database, it will display a `timespan` value of `600000000` as `00:01:00.00` like it would in Visual Studio?

Comment: In database are you storing timespan under int64 data type? I understand that you are.